# Mirror screen from a device to another

Tags: android, casting, sdk, mirroring

I am developing an app to achieve the functionality for Screen Casting from one android device to another android device.

I am developing an app which would be functional like teamviewer i.e. cast other user screen and also want to implement the functionality which identify the screen tap from the destination screen which reflect the action to host screen.

I am using below example's link for implementing the functionality. But not able to achieve the solution for screencast.

1. https://github.com/mmuszkow/ScreenMirroring
2. https://github.com/farmerbb/SecondScreen
3. https://github.com/JonesChi/CastScreen
4. https://integrate.teamviewer.com/en/develop/screen-sharing-sdk/android-tutorial/

Any help will deeply appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

You can not do this Mamta. Not possible in this life.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. It must have some solution.